# cannot find sqlalchemy engine module on OSX

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run a python database software on an apple desktop. However I get this error when running the script:

```
File "/.../python/database.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL  
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy.engine.url
```

Sqlalchemy has already been installed on the machine. And the same code runs flawlessly in Windows and Linux machines. I never had to manually install or correct sqlalchemy modules before. This hiccup only happens in this particular instance. What could the cause be? A path problem, incompatibility or bad install?

Comment: How did you install `sqlalchemy`? Which `python` are you running? Were you able to install other packages and import them? Please include this data in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to find the correct path for python3 and run the main with it. By default it used python2 and the app couldn't run without python3.